# Customize JSON data with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json

I am creating project using nodejs and angularjs. I have json like:

```
[{
    "links": [{
        "description": null,
        "latency": "1",
        "linkid": "26149e91-f6c8-47fb-a10d-691e76486871",
        "contracts": null,
        "tag": null,
        "connections": [
            "ce00ba7c-4916-4920-a7dc-7b70daea9e7a",
            "6d3ec325-4b27-4772-b0d9-36d4cc7b9e47"
        ],
        "type": "0",
        "linkStatus": 1,
        "bandwitdth": 799999
    }, {
        "description": null,
        "latency": "1",
        "linkid": "2f11f857-251f-4b01-9140-12abfda8d79b",
        "contracts": null,
        "tag": null,
        "connections": [
            "bcdc3622-f0b3-4bf2-80fd-3aaee5af1c4c",
            "ca059990-937e-4b29-8a21-615244d56689"
        ],
        "type": "0",
        "linkStatus": 1,
        "bandwitdth": 1024
    }, {
        "description": null,
        "latency": "1",
        "linkid": "7cf69528-13bc-4b90-b952-549fbbab1032",
        "contracts": null,
        "tag": null,
        "connections": [
            "b164c679-f9d9-406d-94a8-b85b99a03bdc",
            "616e4bce-592e-4864-b9f6-149f541fc7d1"
        ],
        "type": "0",
        "linkStatus": 1,
        "bandwitdth": 1024
    }, {
        "description": null,
        "latency": "1",
        "linkid": "d6b67215-6ca5-4f63-8573-e952c132d4af",
        "contracts": null,
        "tag": null,
        "connections": [
            "ebe0a008-29d2-48f9-bd71-4324a0712618",
            "bc36697a-4768-46a1-8e05-62376103b476"
        ],
        "type": "0",
        "linkStatus": 1,
        "bandwitdth": 1024
    }, {
        "description": "TestFlow",
        "latency": "1",
        "linkid": "fd73608aa8e7b440",
        "contracts": null,
        "tag": null,
        "connections": [
            "49b33cd1-5722-4e8e-b40c-03c3407c5efe",
            "cd354769-d52a-414e-bb7c-f0e0690ddf3b"
        ],
        "type": "0",
        "linkStatus": 6,
        "bandwitdth": 0
    }],
    "billing-uuid": "5f1dd7c5-c48b-44ed-be14-cf2a8730fe27"
}]
```

I need `connections` in other json. It should be like:

```
[{
"conn":"49b33cd1-5722-4e8e-b40c-03c3407c5efe"
},
{
 "conn":"49b33cd1-5722-4e8e-b40c-03c3407c5efe"
}]
```

}

My code is like:

```
 var billinData = [];
    var connections = [];
    for(i = 0; i < body.length; i++){
                    billingData.push({"billing-account-uuid":body[i]['billing-uuid']})
                    var nLinksLen = body[i].links.length;

                    for (j = 0; j < nLinksLen; j++){
                        var nConLen = body[i].links[j].connections.length
                        console.log(nConLen)
                        for (k = 0; k < nConLen; k++){
                            connections.push({"vportuuid": body[i].links[j].connections[k]});
                        }
                    }
                }
```

I am getting this with thousand of records with some of duplicates:

```
[
  {
    "conn": "ce00ba7c-4916-4920-a7dc-7b70daea9e7a"
  },
  {
    "conn": "6d3ec325-4b27-4772-b0d9-36d4cc7b9e47"
  }]
```

This does not give correct result.

I just want to know that my loop is correct?

Comment: with duplicate records

Comment: So you want to isolate the connections from the first JSON and place them to another JSON?

Comment: Have your parsed the JSON string?

Comment: @ Subburaj: I updated my question

Comment: @angular make sure that its duplicate or actually present in different connections array??

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `forEach` or `reduce` Array methods to solve this easily:

```
var obj= JSON.parse(...);

var connections=obj.links.reduce(function (array,elem) {
  elem.connections.forEach(function (conn) {
    array.push({'conn': conn});
  }
  return array;
},[]);
```